# How to take input when there is a space between two inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I was solving a problem in hackerrank and they gave me a input "Hack 2" so how do I take this input.
the error is :

HACK 2
         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: go to discussion section on hacker rank.

Answer (score -1):

If those are two separate inputs and you want them to be a single string you could do

```
mystring = input()
```

or

```
mystring = input() + " " + input()
```

or

```
mystring = input() + input()
```

you can 'annotate' the input so it displays a message such as

`input("Enter your text")`

it would also be good if you post your code next time instead of the error